# How to automate vb script

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vbscript

I have this code:

```
Sub NewYearData()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim addy As String, sh As Worksheet
    Dim shName As String
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("PreviousYear.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("CurrentYear2.xlsx")
    addy = "C16:AH18"
    
    For Each sh In wb1.Sheets
        shName = sh.Name
        Set r1 = sh.Range(addy)
        Set r2 = wb2.Sheets(shName).Range(addy)
        r1.Copy r2
    Next sh
    
End Sub
```

Here is a fixed position for cells that I must copy.
In some sheets position is different, so I must find all cells that have references to an external file and sheet like:
`'D:\Data\[Data_1990-2019.xlsx]Set01'!D105`

Question: How to find all cells which contain references, and copy just these cells to a new file?

Answer (score 3):

The following code is copied from the article
[How to find and list all links (external references) in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/953-excel-list-all-links.html)

```
For Each xSheet In Worksheets
    Set xRg = xSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then GoTo LblNext
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If InStr(1, xCell.Formula, "[") > 0 Then
            ...
       End If
    Next
LblNext:
```

You may adapt the above `InStr` call to fit your needs.